# Predicted values based on model with fixed effects

Tags: r, ggplot2, predict

Is there any way you can use ggpredict (from the ggeffects package) with a model containing fixed effects? It seems to me that since employing fixed effects in a model automatically removes one level to function as a reference category, ggpredict will have trouble computing since it is missing that level. Consequently the model contains n-1 levels compared to the data, and ggpredict cannot predict values for a level it has not seen before.

I am interested in plotting a the results from a FE OLS model with interaction effects using the predictions from ggpredict in ggplot. The FEs are essential to my model, but I don't necessarily need to visualize them.

Do anyone have a solution or work-around to my problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `ggpredict` will still be able to predict using the reference fixed effect. Please provide a reproducible example of data and code to demonstrate what you are trying to achieve, as it is very difficult to know how to help you otherwise.

Comment: A fixed effect model doesn't necessarily "remove" levels from (categorical) effects.  Models that include an overall mean term are overparameterised.  This is why it appears that effects for levels of factors are "removed".  They are not: it's just that the model coefficients don't estimate what you think they do.  For example, in a model with an overall mean and a single factor, the "overall mean" actually estimates the response for the "missing" factor level.  As @AllanCameron says, a *reproducible* example will help us judge if this is the case here or if you have a more complex issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.